# Python: Comparing Items in List

Tags: python

I did some research on this topic, Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and still can't crack this bug.

I'm parsing a commentary on a text which is structured by book, chapter and verse. At this stage I have all of the comments separated in order but not organized, and I want to separate each of the comments by book by starting a new element whenever I reach an index of [1,1]. I have a method which extracts that comment's index, which seems so be working just fine (printing the results of `get_comment_index(comment)`, `INDEX1` is `get_comment_index(comment)[0]` and `INDEX2` is `get_comment_index(comment)[1]`:

```
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 1
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 2
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 3
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 4
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 5
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 6
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 7
INDEX1: 1 INDEX2: 9
```

Yet when I try an if statement to catch index1: 1 index2: 1, It't not triggered for some reason. This is what I've tried:

```
if cmp(get_comment_index(comment),[1,1])==0:
if get_comment_index(comment)[0]==1 and get_comment_index(comment)[1]==1:
```

I know this because I put trace lines after the if statement and they're not showing up, even though I know there are such records, as shown above. What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you comparing against the right type? `1` is not the same as `'1'`. `if get_comment_index(comment) == ['1', '1']: ...`

Comment: Why `cmp()`? It was depreciated long ago.

Comment: @AChampion you're right, even though I think of the index as an int, since I getting it using regex it really is a strings. Thanks.

Comment: `print(repr(get_comment_index(comment)))`. Then you'll know exactly what to compeare to.

Answer (score 0):

1. cmp is deprecated. Avoid.
2. Are you sure get_comment_index() is returning a list?

Here's a simulated version of your program:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return [1,1]
... 
>>> cmp(foo(), [1,1])
0
>>> foo()[0]
1
>>> foo()[1]
1
>>>
```

Now, with slight modification:

```
>>> def bar():
...     return (1,1)
... 
>>> cmp(bar(), [1,1])
1
>>> cmp(bar(), [1,1])
1
>>> bar()[0]
1
>>> bar()[1]
1
>>>
```

Comment: I think I should have added it as a comment than as an answer.